# Saving with HABTM in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am creating multiple associations in one go and there are a few problems when it comes to saving.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
foreach($userData as $user) {
    $data = array('User' => array('id' => $user['id']), 'Site' => array('id' => $user['site_id']));
    $this->User->save($data);
}
?>
```

I have experimented with formatting the data array in different ways although I always encounter the same problems. Either the previous entries get moved when a new one is inserted or the current one gets updated.

I could just use the following although I need a behavior to trigger.

```
$this->User->SiteUser->save($data);
```

Edit: Also $this->User->create(); doesn't seem to do much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The IRC helped work out what was wrong, once the **unique** key was set to **false** everything was able to save correctly.

```
//In the user model
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
  'Site' => array(
    'className' => 'Site',
    'unique' => false
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the `id` before a new `save()`, possibly on both models:

```
$this->User->id = null;
```

Cake decides whether to update or insert entries based on the set `id`, and `save()` sets an `id` automatically. Not sure why `create()` doesn't take care of this for you.

Also, if you want to save HABTM data, you should need to use `saveAll()` instead of `save()`. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170141/cakephp-habtm-question/1170155#1170155).